# Закрытие сессии и удаление куки

Tags: сессия, yii2

Есть проект, который реализован на Yii2 и CS-CART. Yii2 на фронтенде, CS-CART на бэкенде. При logout происходит ошибка, как как если разлогиниться на cs-cart сессия не уничтожается и соответственно пользователь считается залогиненным.

Как разлогинить пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы разлогиниться в Yii2 необходимо либо вызвать

```
Yii::$app->user->logout();
```

Либо [вручную очистить куку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie) `PHPSESSID`.

Comment: вот  мне как раз и надо очистить  PHPSESSID

Comment: По ссылке http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie есть подробная инструкция как это делать.

Comment: все не совсем  так просто , дело в том что у меня есть два PHPSESSID ,  с разными поддоменами ,  и  удаляеться только один

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php - Смотрите 4 параметр path. Вы должны в него прописать свой поддомен.